# Программный выбор в ComboBox значения из прикрепленной DataSourse

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите пожалуйста советом! Заполняю BindingList из базы, и прикручиваю его к ComboBox. Код:

```
BindingList<Faculty> source = new BindingList<Faculty>() { };
if ((methods.resultSelect != null) && (methods.resultSelect.ResultData.Rows.Count > 0))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < methods.resultSelect.ResultData.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        source.Add(new Faculty(methods.resultSelect.ResultData.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString(),
                                methods.resultSelect.ResultData.Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString(),
                                methods.resultSelect.ResultData.Rows[i].ItemArray[4].ToString()));
    }
}
// свойство, которое будет отображаться
_cmb_faculty.DisplayMember = "faculty";
//свойство, которое будет возвращаться в качестве значения выбранного айтема
_cmb_faculty.ValueMember = "code_record";
_cmb_faculty.DataSource = source;
```

Вопрос вот в чем: как мне в выпадающем списке ComboBox выбрать конкретный элемент, например 2, если я знаю что значение этого 2 элемента "faculty" равно "12"?

Comment: Wpf или winForms?

Comment: winforms, забыл подписать

Answer (score 1):

Задайте значение свойства вручную

```
_cmb_faculty.SelectedValue = <значение>;
```

Если значение присутствует в прикрепленном списке элементов, то соответствующий элемент будет выбран, если отсутствует - не будет выбран ни один.

Из [описания данного свойства на MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Windows.Forms.ListControl.SelectedValue);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.2);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) можно подумать, что присваивание ему значения должно менять значение свойства прикрепленного элемента, но на самом деле оно ведет себя так же. как `SelectedIndex`, т.е. позволяет указать какой из элементов должен быть отображен.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробовал вот так (для нескольких комбо):

    RASP_EDIT_LIST[countRaspelem].ListObject[0].SelectedValue =source[i].cod_discipline;

 Однако, есть одна фишка. Значение в Combobox не изменяется до тех пор, пока я не **раскрою список элементов**. Именно раскрою, а не выберу элемент

Comment: @АнатолийЧернышов не могу воспроизвести. Все работает как часы. Попробуйте после присваивания значения в SelectedValue вызвать у ComboBox-а метод Update.

Comment: @АнатолийЧернышов под какую версию .NET и разрядность системы проект собираете? Мало ли.

Comment: @АнатолийЧернышов на всякий случай проверил работу с разными источниками данных: DataTable, BindingList и материализованным List из LiNQ-запроса с анонимным типом. Поведение не меняется, все работает. Если найдете что именно у вас вызвало такое поведение ComboBox-а, обязательно напишите, я коллекционирую баги в формах =)

Comment: Пишу под 3.5 и 64-разрядную. Ну будем пробовать)

Comment: @АнатолийЧернышов проверил, не нашел артефактов. Вы чистые формы используете или какой-нибудь DevExpress или аналоги?